# .Net Core 2 Convert C# Variable To Javascript In View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a C# variable *cSharpString* copied over to a JavaScript variable *filename* in my MVC view.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Title";
}

@section head {

    @{
        string cSharpString = "Hello World";
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var filename = "<%=cSharpString%>";
        </script>
    }
}
```

When debugging in Chrome and entering the JavaScript variable name the console outputs the C# code instead of the variable name like I would expect.

> ```
> filename
> "<%=cSharpString%>"
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Razor's `@` wrapped in quotes like these:

```
var filename = '@cSharpString';

// alternative
var filename = "@cSharpString";
```

The `<%= cSharpString %>` can only used in ASPX (webforms engine) page to render text from variable.

Answer (score 0):

You try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var filename = "@cSharpString";
</script>
```